# L33Tify.py Converting characters with a dictionay

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a program that converts normal English input into L33T speak or L33T into English. I can get the first character to appear, but if I put more than one character the program crashes.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: `s/helpful/mandatory/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be accomplished using the dictionary type in python

```
dict = {'a':'4', 'b':"|3"}

str = "ab"

for i in range(len(str)):

    print(dict[str[i]])
```

You just need to complete the dictionary.